# Solve $x+\frac{1}{y-x}=1$, $y+\frac{1}{x-y}=2$

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

I've got this problem:

> Solve for pairs of reals,
>   $$
> \left \{
>   \begin{array}{rcl}
>     x+\dfrac{1}{y-x} & = & 1 \\
>     y+\dfrac{1}{x-y} & = & 2
>   \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

I've tried many different approaches and I tried on *Wolfram Mathematica*, which gives me the solutions, but I don't understand how to prove that there are no other.

> Solution pairs $(x,y)=(2,1)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{2})$.

Comment: It becomes a linear simuotaneous equation if you multiply out by the denominator

Comment: $$\because \frac{1}{y-x}=\frac{1}{-(x-y)}=-\frac{1}{x-y},$$ what happens when you add the equations together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y-x= a $   ⇒ $y=x+a$

$y-1/a=2$

$x+a -1/a=2 $

$x+1/a=1$

Subtracting two relations we get:

⇒$x+1/a-x-a+1/a=1-2   ⇒ a^2-a-2=0 ⇒ a=2,.. a=-1$

$a=2$ gives $y-x=2$ and summing two initial relations gives $x+y=3$. The solution of this system of equation is $x=0,5 $ and $y=2.5$

$a=-1$ gives $y-x=-1$this with $x+y=3$give another system of equation which solution is $x=2$ and $y=1$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if you add both equations you get $x+y=3$. Can you proceed ?

Comment: That was my first thought. But soon I realised it doesn't work by it self.